# Symfony2 : no extension to load Buzz

Tags: php, curl, symfony, buzz

I'm facing an issue while trying to use Curl in Buzz for Symfony2 (I've finally managed to install it, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621949/symfony2-reinstall-issue)).

I use it it one on my bundles, and I've updated services.yml, adding these :

```
# cURL client for Buzz
buzz.client.curl:
class:  Buzz\Client\Curl
public: false
calls:
  - [setVerifyPeer, [false]]

# Buzz browser
buzz.browser:
    class:     Buzz\Browser
    arguments: ['@buzz.client.curl']
```

And when I go and check my project's page, here's the error I get :

```
InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "buzz.client.curl" (in myBundle) Looked for namespace "buzz.client.curl", found none
```

So from what I understand, I have to change one of Buzz's namespace declarations somewhere.
But does anybody know what, and where?

Comment: If your add your answer ans a real answer you can accept it (and I could upvote it :-) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, my mistake, I simply didn't use the right format for my yml file.

Here is the code of the services, in case anyone has the issue. Think of the 4 spaces, that saves a lot of time...

services:

## cURL client for Buzz

```
buzz.client.curl:
    class:  Buzz\Client\Curl
    public: false
    calls:
        - [setVerifyPeer, [false]]
```

## Buzz browser

```
buzz.browser:
    class:     Buzz\Browser
    arguments: ['@buzz.client.curl']
```